# How do I fix "mdadm: /dev/sdc1 not large enough to join array" for three identical discs?

Tags: 12.04, grub2, upgrade, mdadm

After uppgrading to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS in my server grub started to complain and give errors about my raid array, everything still seems to be working but it is a bit unnerving to have grub giving errors.

```
Setting up grub-pc (1.99-21ubuntu3.7) ...
error: found two disks with the index 2 for RAID md0.
error: superfluous RAID member (3 found).
```

I'm getting a lot of these errors when grub is updated.

Facts are: I have three identical discs in a raid5 set up, on two of the discs there is one primary partition which is added to the array but the third disk is added without a primary partition. ie. `mdam --manage /dev/md_d0 --add /dev/sdc`

I'm guessing that this is the reason for grub complaining.

Since discovering this problem I have disabled the disc that is missing a primary partition, created a primary partition, verified that it looks the same with `cfdisk /dev/xxx` and then `Print Partition table`. And tried to add the new partition to the raid array and that is when I get the message that the partition is to small to be added to the raid array.

`> sudo mdadm /dev/md_d0 --add /dev/sdc1`

`mdadm: /dev/sdc1 not large enough to join array`

The partition tables all look the same,

```
 Partition Table for /dev/sdc

               First       Last
 # Type       Sector      Sector   Offset    Length   Filesystem Type (ID) Flag
-- ------- ----------- ----------- ------ ----------- -------------------- ----
   Pri/Log           0        2047*     0#       2048*Free Space           None
 1 Primary        2048* 3907029167*     0  3907027120*Linux raid auto (FD) None

Partition Table for /dev/sdd

               First       Last
 # Type       Sector      Sector   Offset    Length   Filesystem Type (ID) Flag
-- ------- ----------- ----------- ------ ----------- -------------------- ----
   Pri/Log           0        2047*     0#       2048*Free Space           None
 1 Primary        2048* 3907029167*     0  3907027120*Linux raid auto (FD) None

Partition Table for /dev/sde

               First       Last
 # Type       Sector      Sector   Offset    Length   Filesystem Type (ID) Flag
-- ------- ----------- ----------- ------ ----------- -------------------- ----
   Pri/Log           0        2047*     0#       2048*Free Space           None
 1 Primary        2048* 3907029167*     0  3907027120*Linux raid auto (FD) None
```

Or actualy if print the partition table as raw data in cfdisk there is some differences but I can not decipher what that means.

```
-> diff sde.raw sdc.raw 
1c1
 Disk Drive: /dev/sde
---
 Disk Drive: /dev/sdc
30c30
 0x1B0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 B7 E9 70 74 00 00 00 20
---
 0x1B0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 4B 0C 58 1C 00 00 00 20
```

I realized that I could try to copy the mbr from one of the working discs using dd, but still I get the same error even though the partition table is identical in the raw output from cfdisk.

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/sdd of=/tmp/sdd-mbr.bin bs=512 count=1
$ sudo dd if=/tmp/sdd-mbr.bin of=/dev/sdc bs=512 count=1
```

```
$ cat /proc/partitions
major minor  #blocks  name
   8       48 1953514584 sdd
   8       49 1953513560 sdd1
   8       32 1953514584 sdc
   8       33 1953513560 sdc1
   8       64 1953514584 sde
   8       65 1953513560 sde1
```

Now the raw comparison of the partition table gives identical output and the partitions seems to be of the same size but I still get the same error when trying to add `/dev/sdc1` to the array.

I guess my question is if is there is any way to fix this without having to take the whole array apart and recreate it from scratch ?

Output from `mdadm -D /dev/md_d0` the array is still rebuilding since I added /dev/sdc again.

```
/dev/md_d0:
        Version : 0.90
  Creation Time : Sat Aug 14 21:06:13 2010
     Raid Level : raid5
     Array Size : 3907028992 (3726.03 GiB 4000.80 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1953514496 (1863.02 GiB 2000.40 GB)
   Raid Devices : 3
  Total Devices : 3
Preferred Minor : 0
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Fri Jan 11 18:36:06 2013
          State : clean, degraded, recovering 
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 3
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 1

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

 Rebuild Status : 53% complete

           UUID : 74998045:22316376:01f9e43d:ac30fbff (local to host server)
         Events : 0.19988

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       3       8       32        0      spare rebuilding   /dev/sdc
       1       8       64        1      active sync   /dev/sde
       2       8       48        2      active sync   /dev/sdd
```

I realize now that it looks like the whole array is made up of the actual devices rather than the partiotions, then the question is why sdd1 & sde1 partitios are left on the harddrives and over written on /dev/sdc as soon as I add it to the array.

Comment: What does `mdadm -D /dev/md_d0` show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, what's going on is that you originally built the array with the whole disks, without any partitions.  It looks like you may have later added a partition table, which kind of corrupts the array.  You can't add the disk partition now because it is too small since mdadm expects the whole disk.

The errors you see from grub are due to the fact that with the 0.9 metadata format, it can not tell if the raid metadata is supposed to apply to the whole disk, or the partition.  You should rebuild the array using the newer metadata format, and preferably partition the individual disks first this time.

Comment: Ok, so I guess what you are saying is that I will have to start over. There is no way to save the array in its current state ?

Comment: @jeeloo, well, it seems you have re-added the whole drive so the array is fine, but to make grub happy with it yes, you will have to rebuild it.  Actually I *think* you can zero out the superblocks and recreate the array with metadata 1.0 and --assume clean and that would fix it, but certainly have a backup first.

Comment: Can "with the 0.9 metadata format" that be avoided?
I just removed a raid device "just to test", and make changes on the content... and now I cannot join it again.
If I rebuild those partitions i should sync before, and I expected the mdadm to do so. I'll try to sync device with dd then rebuild again the md without formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable HPA on your disk.

## check if HPA enabled

```
$ hdparm -N /dev/sdc

   /dev/sdc:

    max sectors   = 586070255/586072368, HPA is enabled
```

## then disable HPA

```
$ hdparm -N p586072368 /dev/sdc
```

'p' is needed for persistence after reboot. Than you need to reboot your computer an add disk to RAID